# Local website served via ad hoc wifi network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I am in the process of creating a [carputer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carputer) which will be controlled via a web browser on my android device. I plan to use a [raspberry pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) with a USB wireless adapter, which will serve a simple website.

If I use the USB wifi adapter to turn the raspberry pi into an access point/ad-hoc network, can I serve the website from the same device?

At what address (e.g. 192.168.1.1) would I locate the website on my android browser once connecting to the ad-hoc network?

Comment: Depending on what OS you run on the PI, and what services, the IP would be whatever IP you configure it to use.  Without more details, it would be impossible to figure out more about your proposed configuration to have any kind of meaningful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why you should not be able to use it. The address would be whatever your Raspberry's IP is. You will need to install and configure a web server on the PI ([apache](http://www.apache.org/) for example). Once the webserver is up and running, any device on the same network as the PI should be able to connect to the webserver using the PI's IP.

As pointed out by [J. Novack](https://superuser.com/users/206396/j-novack) below, you should also have the PI serve as a [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) server or set up all devices that connect to the PI's network to have static IPs.

Comment: You will need to serve DHCP off the RaspberryPi as well so that your Android device (or anything connecting to it) will get an IP Address automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the tip J, do you have any advice to get started serving DHCP? I'm using Occidentalis v02